# inverse of Tracy–Singh product

Tags: matrices, inverse, kronecker-product

We know that $(A⊗B)^{−1}=A^{−1}⊗B^{−1}$ for kronecker product

Is this true for Tracy–Singh product or Khatri–Rao product which is a kronecker product of partitioned matrices. See wiki kronecker product,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Tracy.E2.80.93Singh_product

That is: is $(A∘B)^{−1}=A^{−1}∘B^{−1}$
true where ∘ denotes Tracy-Singh product.

Comment: yes, it is true. and the question is closed.